Merging spheres with cylinder, UV mapping messed up, normal map isnt continuous (maps had same name)
How do I fix this without needing to remodel the thing ?
I could swear there was an option for autoaligning faces or something. Everything I know of didn't work.
EDIT
I would like the texture/normal map to go through all the way to the tip of the sausage seamlessly, as u can see on the screenshot, there is a ring arround the transition between the cylinder and the sphere (that i merged). I created the sphere in edit mode where i then filled the gaps between the cylinder and sphere. I did the same on both sides.
Blend file: https://we.tl/t-NMQRN6oaEZ
sorry i cannot get the file smaller and idk why, i deleted textures and images but the file keeps getting bigger whenever i save.
thank you so much.
regards <3



We might need a bit more info to understand what "fix this" entails. Also can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.

I edited the post. thanks for taking some time°!

Your blendfile link isn't working. Can you use this site possibly? It's specifically designed to share blend files through stackexchange.

it's probably due to a bad UV mapping of the normal or a bad normal map, but the object you share has no material, please pack the image and share again, also is there a reason why your object is so high-poly?

Hey, I replaced the link to the file with the textures inside now. Sorry I tried getting the file smaller and removed all images from file, didnt work though, and forgot to use the textured file at the end. Thanks for helping!

The "blank" rings you see at either end of your sausage are there because the quads making up those rings are all mapped to a single point in the UV space. Bottom left hand corner where X=0, Y=0.

You say "... i then filled the gaps between the cylinder and sphere." Well you added geometry but forgot to UV unwrap the added geometry. What you should have done,so as not to add to the already unwrapped parts, was to snap the hemispheres to the ends of the cylinder then used the merge tool to merge the overlapping vertices.
Also to avoid visible seams where the hemispheres join the ends of the cylinder (parts that are already using the default Blender UV unwrap) you would need to edit those 3 UV islands in such a way that you can weld the hemisphere UV seam to the end of the cylinder UV sphere so that the 3 UV islands become a single UV island inside the UV space.

Unfortunately to get this right I think you would need to start all over again this time not filling in the gaps between cylinder and hemispheres but instead snap hemisphere edge ring of vertices to cylinder then merge by distance.

nice, but why is it happening even though the image is not here?

@moonboots A good question for someone at Blender Stack Exchange?

